# Installing and using Magic Trackpad on Windows XP (without Boot Camp)

Tags: windows-xp, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

I can't use the Magic Trackpad on my Windows XP. It can be paired, but it will not control the cursor. Drivers form boot camp (`AppleWirelessTrackpadInstaller.exe`) are installed.

I have a lot of errors in the system log from BTHUSB, with code 5. Text is

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   BTHUSB
Event Category: None
Event ID:   5
Date:       2011-03-21
Time:       02:53:03
User:       N/A
Computer:   XXXSTATION
Description:
The driver expected an HCI event with a given size but did not receive it.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 00 00 0e 00 01 00 5e 00   ......^.
0008: 00 00 00 00 05 00 05 c0   .......À
0010: 13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........
0018: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........
0020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........
0028: 05 00 00 00 06 00 00 00   ........
0030: 13 06 01 01 00 01         ......
```

My bluetooth is `ISSCEDRBTA USB\VID_1131&PID_1001\5&13956077&0&2 USB\Vid_1131&Pid_1001&Rev_0373`, its driver is "Generic bluetooth radio".

How can I make it work?

---

`btdiscovery` was able to list services available from Trackpad:

```
bin>btdiscovery.exe -s
(40:A6:D9:xx:xx:4B)     Apple Wireless Trackpad Unknown
        1124    0       Apple Wireless Trackpad
        1200    0
```

---

Checked on another PC from clean install with same bluetooth dongle. Before installing Apple driver, the trackpad works as single button mouse (with MS driver). After installing drivers from somewhere online, the Trackpad doesn't work and not listed in "device manager" as mouse.

---

Current problem is not on the second PC (it works ok now), but on first.

**When I try to enable "mice" bluetooth service of in properties of my Bluetooth device (trackpad), I get a error after pressing Apply, like the "Denied".** And mice bluetooth service is not enabled.

Comment: My current drivers for bluetooth  are from http://digiex.net/drivers/153-driver-isscedrbta-bluetooth-dongle-windows-xp-sp2.html

Comment: reinstalled driver from http://www.bvanleeuwen.nl/faq/?p=582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of the last problem is [this one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/xpru/thread/0b0c7a8e-4cd8-4d1b-a743-7606de0becae/).

*Sys.Panel → Administration → Services → Bluetooth Support Service*

Run as System Service (first radio button), not as Local Service user.